# MAHAPPS.METRO DEMO Sample: XAML.CS files visible but related XAML views not displayed

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have opened the MahApps.Metro code in Visual Studio 2017. I want to look at the XAML files that the MainWindow.XAML is binding to, but they do not appear in the MahApps.Metro.Demo.Shared -> ExampleViews folder. However, the XAML.CS files do appear, but not the associated XAML file. I know the project can see the XAML files, because it builds and runs okay, but I don't see them in the Solution Explorer.

Is there some setting that will make them appear, so I can see the XAML code in the designer window? Is this a problem because these are shared files used by two other projects, the MahApps.Metro.Demo.Net45 and MahApps.Metro.Demo.Net40?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Windows 8.1 SDK, the XAML files in the shared project finally appears in Visual Studio 2017 (2015).

[image]

Blog posts found about this issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26291339-e8fd-4596-980a-7befa63a1f7c/missing-folders-files-add-item-options-in-shared-project?forum=visualstudiogeneral

https://www.cool-it.at/blog/Oktober-2016/Visual-Studio-2015-Fehlende-Code-Behind-Verknupfun

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you were on the right track here with the install not being complete or having all the components it needed. However, just adding in the component above as well as others did not resolve the issue. I ended up installing Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows 10 box and the Solution Explorer did show the XAML files and I can see the markup in Visual Studio as well, so what a relief. Thank you for your feedback, it was very helpful!